# trouble posting ajax data to python funtion

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension with a background page that contains the variable **url**. I'm trying to send **url** to my python code, but I get "400 (BAD REQUEST)" in my background logs and no errors in my python logs.

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log("receiving URL");
    console.log(request);
    var articleUrl = request;
    console.log(articleUrl)
    // sending URL to python
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: `${url}/buttoncolor`,
        data: articleUrl,
        success: function myFunction(data) {
        console.log("just sent the url to buttoncolor")
        }
    })

});
```

**application.py:**

```
@application.route('/buttoncolor', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def buttoncolor():
    print ("buttoncolor")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if not request.form['articleUrl']:
            flash('Please enter the url field', 'error')
        else:
            rurl = request.form['articleUrl']
            print("here comes rurl")
            print(rurl)
```

print ("buttoncolor") works fine, but print("here comes rurl") does not appear. I have another chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener with an $.ajax in background.js that posts and gets fine to another function in application.py.

Answer (score 0):

modify your ajax data

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log("receiving URL");
    console.log(request);
    var articleUrl = request;
    console.log(articleUrl)
    // sending URL to python
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: `${url}/buttoncolor`,
        data:{articleUrl: articleUrl},
        success: function myFunction(data) {
        console.log("just sent the url to buttoncolor")
        }
    })

});
```

Comment: Then the problem is from your backend then

Comment: Another ajax post in the same .js file works fine — and it interacts with the same .py file. And data isn't coming from a backend, it's a variable created in the .js